# ¿Se puede poner 2 name a un input?

Tags: php, html

Concretamente tengo un formulario el cual tiene que llenar una tabla u otra dependiendo de la primera opcion elegida, el problema es que los input son los mismos para ambas tablas y tengo que incluirle los 2 name al mismo, ¿es esto posible?, en la prueba que hize me lleno la tabla pero todo en blanco.

Esta seria mi codigo php:

```
if($boton == "Guardar"){

    if($rol == 1){

        $pg = "insert into usuarios (usuario, clave, id_rol, correo_usuario) values ('$usuario', '$encriptar', '$rol', '$usuario')";

        $pg1 = "insert into analista (nombre_analista, apellido_analista, correo_analista, telefono_analista, cedula_analista) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";

        if(pg_query($pg) && pg_query($pg1)){

            $_SESSION['guardo'] = $guardo;

        }else{

            echo $error;
        }
    }else if($rol == 2){

        $pg = "insert into usuarios (usuario, clave, id_rol, correo_usuario) values ('$usuario', '$encriptar', '$rol', '$usuario')";

        $pg1 = "insert into instructor (nombre_instructor, apellido_intructor, correo_instructor, telefono_instructor, cedula_instructor) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";

        if(pg_query($pg) && pg_query($pg1)){

            $_SESSION['guardo'] = $guardo;

        }else{

            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
```

Y los input los tengo basicamen asi:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre_analista, nombre_instructor" class="form-control">
```

Si se puede ponerle los 2 name al mismo input o existe otra forma de hacer lo que necesito

Comment: NO, no podras porque el `name` es unico por formulario, asi que tendrias que buscar otra solucion.

Comment: Podrias dejar cualquiera de los dos nombres y ya dependiendo de tu opcion rol ingresas a  la tabla que necesites esos datos

Comment: No me queda muy clara tu pregunta, pero creo que pudieras usar un name genérico por ejemplo "nombre" y usar dicha variable en ambos insert, a final de cuentas llevará el dato que ocupas y el if controla el flujo hacia el insert correcto.

Comment: Si, utilize un name generico y ya me funciona como necesito. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sugerencia de optimización**: usala o ignórala según te dicte tu corazón:

Si rol solo puede tomar los valores 1 y 2, puedes simplificar tu código metiendo en el if solo aquella parte que cambia según el rol:

```
if($boton == "Guardar"){
    $pg = "insert into usuarios (usuario, clave, id_rol, correo_usuario) values ('$usuario', '$encriptar', '$rol', '$usuario')";

    if($rol == 1) //analista
{       
        $pg1 = "insert into analista (nombre_analista, apellido_analista, correo_analista, telefono_analista, cedula_analista) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";
    }else //instructor ($rol == 2)
{
        $pg1 = "insert into instructor (nombre_instructor, apellido_intructor, correo_instructor, telefono_instructor, cedula_instructor) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";
} 
        if(pg_query($pg) && pg_query($pg1)){

            $_SESSION['guardo'] = $guardo;
        }else{
            echo $error;
        }
}
```

Comment: Si al principio iba hacerlo asi, pero luego pense que si me daba algun error en el guardado de las consultas y aun asi guardaba el usuario y pues me confundiria despues

Comment: Excelente sugerencia, pero, ¿por qué conservas el `if ... elseif `?

Comment: Tienes razón, lo dejé porque me estaba preguntando que pasa si tiene más de un rol, ahora lo corrijo

Comment: @A.Cedano debido a que aún no sabemos si hay mas de un rol, lo comenté para mejor entendimiento de Edwin

Answer (score 0):

Primero te diría que limpiases el PHP así, trabajando con switch y sin repetir cosas:

```
if ($boton == "Guardar") {
    switch ($rol) {
        case 1:
            $pg1 = "insert into analista (nombre_analista, apellido_analista, correo_analista, telefono_analista, cedula_analista) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";
            break;
        case 2:
            $pg1 = "insert into instructor (nombre_instructor, apellido_intructor, correo_instructor, telefono_instructor, cedula_instructor) values ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$cedula')";
            break;
    }
    $pg = "insert into usuarios (usuario, clave, id_rol, correo_usuario) values ('$usuario', '$encriptar', '$rol', '$usuario')";
    if (pg_query($pg) && pg_query($pg1)) {
        $_SESSION['guardo'] = $guardo;
    } else {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Luego en el caso de html el input debe tener como `name` "nombre" a secas y trabajarlo de una forma u otra en función del rol.

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control">
```

Ni se pueden poner dos names ni se debe, el tema es que te las apañes para usar un solo name por form.

Espero haber ayudado!